# Wordpress Media Library in plain javascript

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I'm working with wordpress and I'm creating a theme for myself. I want to use the wordpress media library in the admin panel. So after some searching I found this page: https://codex.wordpress.org/Javascript_Reference/wp.media

There are multiple tutorials to add this media library with jQuery, but I would like to do it in a plain javascript way. I've no trouble converting the jQuery to javascript except this piece of code:

```
// When an image is selected in the media frame...
    frame.on( 'select', function() {
        // Removed unrelevant code
  });
```

Ive tried the following things:

```
frame.select = function(){};
frame.onselect = function(){};
frame.addEventListener('select',function(){});
```

None of them are working, I get an error on the last one:

> frame.addEventListener is not a function

So I hope I can get some help from here. I love everyone trying to help, but I don't want to hear: "use jQuery". The choice for not using jQuery is one I made on purpose.

StefanJanssen